# Document or describe what a specific Gmail filter is for

Tags: gmail, gmail-labels

I have a lot of Gmail filters set up, and it's hard to remember what each one is for.

Is there any way I can add a short comment or description to each one?

Answer (score 4):

Currently I am using the `from` field for this so that it appears in the beginning. For example, I type `-(DOC: My message here)` which becomes `from:(-(DOC: My message here))`, and doesn't affect the filter at all, since it is very unlikely that someone's name or email matches the message I write.

To clarify, for this message to affect the filter, the from address must match all of my comment in any order (e.g. if a message is from `my.message.doc.here@example.com`, then yes, it will be excluded from the filter, incorrectly). If only some of the words match, the message will still be included (e.g. if a message is from `message@example.com`, it will still match the filter).

I'm open to other (hopefully better) suggestions.